# Yup validation with FieldsArray, ReactJS, redux-from

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, yup

I working with yup validation and trying to build a conditional validation object

Normally, I use Field in redux form to handle form input value and validation it with yup, but In another case, I use FieldArray to implement complicate condition, this is a code I use FieldArray:

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FieldArray
          name="session"
          component={RenderSession}
        />
 </form>
```

this is component I bind in FieldsArray,

```
export const RenderSession = ({ fields }) => {return (
  {fields.map((member, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <Field
        name={`${member}.name`}
        validate={validateProps}
      />
    </div>
    <Button onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
      Add
    </Button>
  </Row>
</>
```

I want to check validations the value of the field name = {`$ {member} .startTime`} how to use yup
Please give me a solution for using yup with FieldsArray or anything else. In the case of this impossible, teach me to have another way,
Feel free to question,
Thanks

Comment: give me 1 hope, Plzzz

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Comment: May be you can use Yup.test('isValid', value => {// return true or false})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from Yup docs you can check the element of an array against its schema, IE:

```
array().of(object().shape({ num: number().max(4) }))
```

ref: https://github.com/jquense/yup#arrayoftype-schema-schema

or a more fitting example:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  friends: Yup.array()
    .of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string()
          .min(4, 'too short')
          .required('Required'), // these constraints take precedence
        salary: Yup.string()
          .min(3, 'cmon')
          .required('Required'), // these constraints take precedence
      })
    )
    .required('Must have friends') // these constraints are shown if and only if inner constraints are satisfied
    .min(3, 'Minimum of 3 friends'),
});
```

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini What if I want to pass dynamic min and max values?

Comment: Hi mate, it will look like:  `Yup.string().min(4, 'too short').max(8, 'too long')`